# FAQ proposal - review can be general

Tags: discussion

I think that we should amend our FAQ to say:

> **Reviewers may comment on any part of the code.**
>   Feel free to call attention to specific areas you are concerned about (performance, formatting, etc). However, any aspect of the code posted is fair game for criticism.

[Find the non repeating number in the integer array](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1434/110) is the question that prompted this edit. It asks specifically for a way to increase the efficiency of the code. The question I had was if it was on topic, since it asked for specific code.

[This answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1434/find-the-non-repeating-number-in-the-integer-array/1455#1455) does not address that need, but still is a good "code review" answer. I think that the question is good, but that the scope of the answers shouldn't be limited to only what the OP had in mind.

There is not a problem now per se, but sepp2k and I believe that it would be good to clarify this.

Any opinions or edits?

Comment: I don't oppose this at all, but I'm curious -- can you provide links that prompted it? I would like to see evidence / background.

Comment: @Jeff - I've edited the context into the question. I noticed it because it was asking for a specific answer - using hashmaps to achieve greater efficiency. The consensus between sepp2k and I was that it was fine to ask that sort of question here, but the reviewers shouldn't be limited in scope to that request.

Answer (score 4):

OK, I didn't see any harm in this, so I edited it into the FAQ.

This is something you can do as a diamond mod as well, just click edit there.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to try and get some feedback on it :)